# how to receive username with token by django rest authetication?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, authorization, django-rest-auth

I am using django Django=2.1.7 and rest framework djangorestframework=3.9.2 This is my url for login

```
path('rest-auth/login', include('rest_auth.urls')),
```

When I enter username and password I got the token from rest API. But I want my user detail like name, id etc to show in my react components. Please help me how to achieve. I have seen many answers on StackOverflow even the official documentation is not descriptive https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: Can you show the package you are using? (`rest_auth`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use rest-auth you can get the id, username, email, first_name and last_name of the logged user using this URL: http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned package provides us the ability to [override the settings](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)
In the login process, the response comes from either **`TOKEN_SERIALIZER`** or **`JWT_SERIALIZER`**. In your case, I assume that you are not using the ***JWT*** method.
So, create a new serializer class as per your desired structure and wire it up using ***`REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS`*** settings dictionary.
Here is one sample

```
#serializer.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')


class MyCustomTokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Token
        fields = ('key', 'user')
```

and in your ***`settings.py`***,

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.custom.MyCustomTokenSerializer',
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to automatically populate user data once a user logs in.  You should just be able to take the username the user entered during the login process, save it in a variable, and after receipt of token make another API call to get the user information.

Comment: what if I need user Id which is most important for me for some API call.